# 3 images per row

Tags: image, wordpress, count, row

I want to retrieve the images from a custom field (Wordpress) and display 3 images per row. In addition i would like to add a

tag per row. So it would look like this:

`<ul>
<li>image1</li>
<li>image2</li>
<li>image3</li>
</ul>`

`<ul>
<li>image4</li>
<li>image5</li>
<li>image6</li>
</ul>`

I have found some code and tried some custom coding to achieve this. Almost got it working, but i need a `</ul>` tag after the last retrieved image. The code below will generate the `</ul>` tag just before the last retrieved image... In addition, I am not very familiar with arrays and loops, so there might be an easier solution to achieve this than the code below.

Who can help me out? Thank you so much for yr time!

```
<?php 

// vars
$images = array();
$row = 0;
$i = 0;
$gallery_images = get_field('galerie' );


// loop through gallery images and sort into the $images array
if( $gallery_images )
{
    foreach( $gallery_images as $image )
    {

        // Insert the url tag
        if ( $i === 0 ) 
        {
                 echo "<ul class='galerieul'>";
        }

        // increase $i
        $i++;
 // Insert the url tag
        if( $i > 3 )
        {
            echo "<ul class='galerieul'>";
        }
        // if $i has increased above 3, increase the row and reset $i
        if( $i > 3 )
        {    
        $i = 1;
        $row++;
        }


    // add image to row
        $images[ $row ][] = $image;
 ?>
   <li class="customimagestyle">
                    <?php echo $image['title']; ?><br />
                    <a href="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" rel="lightbox"><img src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['thumbnail']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" /></a><br />
                    <?php echo $image['description']; ?>
                </li>

                <?php
// Insert the url tag

         if ( $i === 3 ) 
        {
             echo "</ul>";
        }
        if ($i < $row) 
        { 
            echo '</ul>'; 
        }

    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Is `get_field` defined [here](http://podsframework.org/codex/get_field)?  If so, it returns a scalar, and you can't iterate over a scalar.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12280198/display-2-or-3-images-per-row-using-php-mysql?

Comment: Im sorry, the get_field is working here.. It is just about wrapping 3 images in a <ul> tag..

Answer (score 1):

Use the [modulus](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) operator, and be sure to check for a partially-filled row, e.g.,

```
<?php

// loop through gallery images and sort into the $images array
if( $gallery_images )
{
    $i = 0;
    foreach( $gallery_images as $image )
    {

        if ( ($i % 3) == 0 ) {
           echo "<ul class='galerieul'>";
        }

 ?>
        <li class="customimagestyle">
              <?php echo $image['title']; ?><br />
              <a href="
              <?php echo $image['url']; ?>" rel="lightbox"><img src="
              <?php echo $image['sizes']['thumbnail']; ?>" alt="
              <?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" /></a><br />
              <?php echo $image['description']; ?>
         </li>

<?php

        if (($i % 3) == 0) {
           echo "</ul>";
        }

        $i++;
    }

    // Close the ul tag, in the case of a partially-filled row
    if (($i % 3) != 0) {
       echo "</ul>";
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion I am trying to understand your code.. but cannot seems to get it working. What would the total code look like with your solution? Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks a lot, it opens the ul tag <li class="customimagestyle"> every 3 images, but it closed the ul tag after every 1 image.. Maybe you can figure out what is going wrong?

Comment: actually after an <ul> has been opened the first image after that gets closed with the </ul> tag.. I guess because the `$i++;` is not present anymore?

Comment: Try setting $i = 1 and not 0

Comment: That will delete all the <ul> opening tags..just to be clear.. the opening tags are placed at the right positions but the closing </ul> tag is placed after every single image that is generated after the opening <ul> tag..

Answer (score 0):

Is `get_field('galerie' )` working? Are you able to get the images in the gallery?

Remember that images (attachments) are stored as posts. So if you know the ID of post t hat has the gallery, this should not be a problem.

Here are some code / solutions that might help you (not tested):

```
function display_images_in_list($size = thumbnail) {

    if($images = get_posts(
        array(
        'post_parent'    => get_the_ID(),
        'post_type'      => 'attachment',
        'numberposts'    => -1, // show all
        'post_status'    => null,
        'post_mime_type' => 'image',
            'orderby'        => 'menu_order',
            'order'           => 'ASC')
        )
    ){
        foreach($images as $image) {
            $attimg   = wp_get_attachment_image($image->ID,$size);
            echo $attimg;
        }
    }
}
```

Source: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/list-all-images-attached-to-a-post-based-on-gallery

```
function aldenta_get_images($size = 'thumbnail') {
  global $post;

  $photos = get_children( 
    array(
      'post_parent' => $post->ID, 
      'post_status' => 'inherit', 
      'post_type' => 'attachment', 
      'post_mime_type' => 'image', 
      'order' => 'ASC', 
      'orderby' => 
      'menu_order ID') 
  );

  $results = array();

  if ($photos) {
    foreach ($photos as $photo) {
    // get the correct image html for the selected size
    $results[] = wp_get_attachment_image($photo->ID, $size);
  }

  return $results;
}
```

Source: http://snipplr.com/view/52857/

Comment: I am able to retrieve the images in the gallery. The only thing is that i would like to add the ul/li style to the images, so that i can do some better custom styling.. Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ah, okey, I thought you had not retrieved the images. @emallove's suggestion is the way to go then. Just fine tune the code.

Comment: Okay thank you. I don't have it working yet as you can see, I'll try some things out but... maybe you have any idea why it generates the </ul> after 1 image, everytime the <ul> tag is generated?